# Appending Colored Text To Rich Text Box From Separate Thread

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

A while ago I found the following code on Code Project ([Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/269787/Accessing-Windows-Forms-Controls-across-Threads)) that helps me adds some text to my Rich Text Box from another thread:

```
delegate void UpdateMessageLog(Control ctrl, string text);

public static void UpdateText(Control ctrl, string text)
{
    if (ctrl.InvokeRequired)
    {
        UpdateMessageLog delUpdate = new UpdateMessageLog(UpdateText);
        ctrl.Invoke(delUpdate, ctrl, text);
    }
    else
    {
            ctrl.Text += text;
        }
    }
```

This is needed because I am developing a simple UDP-based chat application with c# in WinForms and my listening server method is running on a different thread, thus if a message is received, it's text is updated to the RTB using the above code. Here is my Server Method:

```
private void serverThread()
{
    UdpClient udpReceiveClient = new UdpClient(8082);

    while (true)
    {
        IPEndPoint ConnectingIPEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        byte[] receivedBytes = udpReceiveClient.Receive(ref ConnectingIPEndPoint);
        string sMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receivedBytes);

        UpdateText(rtbTextWindow, Environment.NewLine + "Sound Desk: " + sMessage);
    }
}
```

Then later on I found code that lets me add colored text to the RTB and helps me color different text with different colors:

```
private void AppendText(RichTextBox box, Color color, string text)
{
    int start = box.TextLength;
    box.AppendText(text);
    int end = box.TextLength;

    // Textbox may transform chars, so (end-start) != text.Length
    box.Select(start, end - start);
    {
        box.SelectionColor = color;
        // could set box.SelectionBackColor, box.SelectionFont too.
    }
    box.SelectionLength = 0; // clear
}
```

Here is an example of where I use it - When the current client is sending a message, it's own message is also added to the RTB:

```
private void btnSend_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    AppendText(this.rtbTextWindow, Color.GreenYellow, Environment.NewLine + "Front Stage: ");
    AppendText(this.rtbTextWindow, Color.Black, txtMsg.Text);
    SendOverUDP(txtMsg.Text);

    //Clear Text
    txtMsg.Clear();
    txtMsg.Focus();
}
```

Now this works great if I'm using it to append colored text to the RTB that the current client is sending, but received text from a different node (being received from the server thread) needs a different solution, since the `AppendText` Method does not check or handle the 'InvokeRequired' Aspect of the RTB.

Comment: Where is the `AppendText` call?

Comment: I Updated post to include the call now. I call the `AppendText` Method to include the current sending node's message in the RTB as well

Comment: You don't show **where** you show **how**.

Comment: Do you call `btnSend_Click` also in server thread instead of using it only as event handler?

Comment: btn_Send is for sending a message from A to B, whereas the server thread is listening for messages from B. So btn_Send is used to send and server thread is used to receive

Comment: Are you asking how to use `control.Invoke` to call the `AppendText` method?

Comment: Still unclear your question. What is your exact issue? Do you have cross-thread exception or other? Where do you get it exactly?

Comment: Yes, I like to know how to invoke the AppendText method from the second thread.

Comment: I should add, I have not worked with multi-threading programming a lot at all, so if I am overlooking a obvious solution, do tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This first thing you need to understand is that any user interface (UI) objects can only be updated on the UI thread.  That includes your reference to txtMsg.

You are probably communicating with the other end of your chat on a separate background thread.  So, in order to update your UI, you have to jump or *Invoke* into the UI thread to update it.

Your "`UpdateText()`" method gives you all the clues as to how to do this for AppendText.  First, though, is that you cannot even reference a UI control from a background thread.

Also--as a side note--there is a generic delegate, known as `Action`, that eliminates the need for defining a delegate, such as that UpdateMessageLog delegate.

So, a simple pattern to follow, whenever you wish to update any control, would be as follows:

```
void UpdateControl(object dataToApply)
{
    if (myControl.InvokeRequired)
    {
        myControl.Invoke(new Action<object>(UpdateControl), dataToApply);
    }
    else
    {
         //Code goes here to apply the update.  This will run on the UI thread, 
         //such as your call to update your RichTextBox:
         AppendText(this.rtbTextWindow, Color.Black, dataToApply);
    }
}
```

You can look up the `Action<>` generic delegate for details on how to pass different types and numbers of parameters.  `Func<>` can be used if you need to return a value from a UI control.  Please note, the type (`object`) that I used above was just to show you an example--in your case,  you would probably want to make that a `string`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, all you want is to make `AppendText` "thread-aware" like `UpdateText`. And the pattern is always one and the same - check for `InvokeRequired` and if yes, create and invoke a delegate to the method, otherwise just execute the normal method code. Like this

```
private void AppendText(RichTextBox box, Color color, string text)
{
    if (box.InvokeRequired)
    {
        box.Invoke(new Action<RichTextBox, Color, string>(AppendText), box, color, text);
        return;
    }
    // The existing code ...
}
```